# WPF vs Silverlight in designing sound analysis and editing application (I'm new to .Net)

Tags: wpf, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, audio, desktop-application

I want to create a Windows Desktop App with C#. I'm fairly new to .Net and not so bright in software development whatsoever, but I'm keen to learn, and do it with ambitious project. I installed Visual Studio 2012 (even though I'm on Win7, which is mostly irrelevant), and the Dilemma is in what kind of project I need, **WPF** or **Silverlight**.

The App is based on sound analysis and editing.

The App will create PDF file based on sound analysis.

By sound analysis I mean going deep into Digital Sound Processing.

Sounds may vary from .mp3 files to recorded .wav files.

As I said, I'm fairly new to IT Development, so please do not rush into trolling if the question might be too elementary.

PS: Please be free to recommend me different resources on studying differences between the two (but please recommend the ones that are really for dummies =) ).

Thank you for assistance.

Comment: Silverlight has been put in the list of "abandoned" technologies by Microsoft, while WPF is the preferred option for .Net Windows Desktop Applications.

Comment: Thanks, I will stick with **WPF** then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to develop a Desktop Application, use **WPF**.